# Remove entered and left rows in chatrooms in pidgin

Tags: xmpp, pidgin

How do i remove "entered" and "left" rows in chatrooms in pidgin?

```
xx left the room (Disconnected: closed).

xx entered the room.
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The Join/Part Hiding plugin included with pidgin does this.

Answer (score 6):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> to open the Plugin list.

Scroll down to 'Join/Part Hiding'. Check the box and configure the plugin.

I set it to hide those messages in a room over the size of 2.